# How can embed PowerBI report server in my web App and user can see all his reports whit out loggining into it

Tags: asp.net-core, powerbi, single-sign-on, embed, dashboard

I want when a user login to my web app (which is written by asp.net core) and click on a button, user can enter power bi report server with out any authorization any more is that possible? not only see a dashboard or report but the same as if he login to his user separately.